# Null Reference Exception on scaffolded Identity Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My project is ASP.Net MVC5 and uses ASP Identity. I ran the scaffolding commands and have made minor changes to the view layouts. I recently noticed that when the login page loads, during debugging, I get the error below:
[image]

I haven't changed the controller and I'm not sure how the exception is being thrown as the the page loads fine if you continue and the login functions normally.

The unmodified controller code is below:

```
//
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

I must point out that this only occurred after adding DevExpress into the project but DevExpress support insists this is not expected behaviour.

How would I begin to trace something like this? What is null? Clicking "View Details" on the error dialog doesn't show an inner exception and the StackTrace is `null`, the source is `Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly`.